# Two models, two fields, return preferred if present

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Been struggling with how to do this the most optimized way possible...

I have two models: `Catalog` and `Application`.

`Catalog` has a field called `name`.

`Application` has a field called `name`.

Both have a relationship with each other.

I am struggling to find a way to create a function i could use across my Laravel application which i would pass `application.id` to it and it would return a `$app->name` value based on the following logic:

- if `$application->name` exists, use this value as the `$app->name` for the `$application` object
- otherwise, get the `$catalog->name` value and use it as the `$app->name`

Note that I would like to create a component `@application()` where i can simply pass the `$application->id` and build the display logic (theming/styling) into it.

Since i display this `$app->name` in many places, i would like to make it as lightweight as possible to avoid unnecessary queries.

I hope this makes sense! There are probably so many ways to go with it, i am lost at figuring out the way way to do this :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure to understand your model/DB design, but you could use a custom Helper to use that function through the whole app.

For that, you can create a simple PHP class `Helper.php` file in `app/Http/Helpers` folder or whatever location you want. Something like:

```php
<?php

use App\Catalog;
use App\Application;

if (! function_exists('getAppName')) {
    function getAppName($id){
        // Do your logic here to return the name
        $catalog = Catalog::find($id);
        return $catalog->name;
    }
}
?>
```

Then in any controller or view, you just do
`getAppName($application->id)`

Do no  forget to add your helpers file to the composer autoload. So in `composer.json` in Laravel's root folder, add the helper path to the autoload array:

```
"files": [
    "app/Http/Helpers/helpers.php"
],
```

Last but not least, run the following command:
`composer dump-autoload`

Please note that function logic is just for sample purposes since I don't know your model structure.

Comment: Thanks! Would it make sense to cache this `$catalog` call?

Comment: It depends on how often a catalog will be updated. Just keep in mind that cached queries need to be cleared if the model changes. Despite if you are using files or database you would need to perform a `forget` or `flush` once an update is done. In the same way, the query which returns the catalog will be a little more complex because retrieving info from the cache or database if it does not exist. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I care about the database cost.

Use ternary expression will be elegant. But it took two times IO costs from database if application name is empty.

```php
$app_name = Application::find($id)->name;
$app_name = empty($app_name) ? Catalog::where('application_id', $id)->first()->name;
```

And this will more complicated, but the catalog_query only execute when `application.name` is `empty`, it execute in database and the result is taken out only once;

And Database will only find the name from one table or two table.

Something like this:

```php
$catalog_query = Catalog::where('catalogs.application_id', $id)->select('catalogs.name')->groupBy('catalogs.name'); 
// if catalogs and applications relationship is 1:1, use ->limit(1) or remove groupBy('name') is better.

Application::where("applications.id", $id)
           ->selectRaw("IF(application.name IS NULL OR application.name = '', (" . $catalog_query->toSql() ."), applications.name ) AS app_name")
           ->mergeBindings($catalog_query->getQuery())
           ->first()
           ->app_name;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It does help. I appreciate it. Really trying to keep what i am building as efficient as it can be. Thanks!